# mapreduce to read hive table and write to hdfs location with context

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hcatalog

I am looking out for the mapreduce program to read from one hive table and write to hdfs location of first column value of each record. And it should contain only map phase not reducer phase.

Below is the mapper

```
public class Map extends Mapper<WritableComparable, HCatRecord, NullWritable, IntWritable> {

      protected void map( WritableComparable key,
                        HCatRecord value,
                        org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper<WritableComparable, HCatRecord,
                        NullWritable, IntWritable>.Context context)
          throws IOException, InterruptedException {
          // The group table from /etc/group has name, 'x', id
        //  groupname = (String) value.get(0);
          int id = (Integer) value.get(1);
          // Just select and emit the name and ID
          context.write(null, new IntWritable(id));
      }
  }
```

Main class

```
public class mapper1   {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    mapper1 m=new mapper1();
        m.run(args);
    }

    public void run(String[] args) throws IOException, Exception, InterruptedException {
    Configuration conf =new  Configuration();


    // Get the input and output table names as arguments
    String inputTableName = args[0];

    // Assume the default database
    String dbName = "xademo";

    Job job = new Job(conf, "UseHCat");
    job.setJarByClass(mapper1.class);
    HCatInputFormat.setInput(job, dbName, inputTableName);

    job.setMapperClass(Map.class);

    // An HCatalog record as input
    job.setInputFormatClass(HCatInputFormat.class);

    // Mapper emits a string as key and an integer as value
    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(NullWritable.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);


    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath((JobConf) conf, new Path(args[1]));


    job.waitForCompletion(true);
    }
}
```

Is there anything wrong in this code?

This is giving some error as Numberformat exception from string 5s. I am not sure where it is being taken from. Showing error at below line HCatInputFormat.setInput()

Comment: Are you not allowed to just write a Hive query to do this? Can you please add the stacktrace to the question?

Comment: Yes, I can but i have some requirement which would have some transformations in between which we thought of writing MR. In the above program, what might i have missed.

Comment: A transformation that cannot be done by a UDF? Or even using Spark would be less code than Mapreduce

Comment: Thats correct but i want to understand what is wrong with the above code.

Comment: You mention a string "5s", but I don't know where that is, or you dataset. You should provide the stacktrace for where the error occurs, but how do you know that `value.get(1)` will be an integer? `HCatInputFormat` has no schema associated with the records, correct?

Comment: It does  hold the varchar values from the input table. And the error occuring at HCatInputFormat.setInput(......). Even if i comment the map implemention, the error is same..

Comment: Can you please [edit] the question to show the data and the stacktrace?